# Whats the function of "da" in connection with verbs?

Tags: verb, prefix

As I figured, *da* has several meanings. How is it understood, when it comes together with a verb?

Consider the following statements

> Und jeder Priester *steht da* und verrichtet täglich den Gottesdienst und bringt öfters dieselben Opfer dar, welche doch niemals Sünden wegnehmen können
>
> Also fiel ich nieder vor dem HERRN die vierzig Tage und vierzig Nächte, die ich *dalag*; denn der HERR sprach, er wollte euch vertilgen.
>
> Die Nachbarn und die ihn zuvor gesehen hatten, dass er ein Bettler war, sprachen: Ist dieser nicht, der *dasaß* und bettelte?
>
> Gott sprach zu Mosche: Ich werde *dasein*, als der ich *dasein* werde. Und er sprach: So sollst du zu den Söhnen Jissraels sprechen: ICH BIN DA schickt mich zu euch.

Is it all about location somehow? For instance in the first sentence the context does not give any hint *where* he actually is standing. Is it simply implying, that he is *there*, as in being there, standing?

Comment: Though this does not apply to your question, be aware that biblical language is quite different from regular German.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/meaning-of-da-in-this-sentence

Comment: also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12012/what-does-da-kommt-sein-schiff-an-eine-kleine-insel-mean

Comment: for a very detailed look see here: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/meaning-da/

Answer (score 4):

"Da (sein)" can mean "(being) here|there|(at some place)" to express the existance or presence of something or someone, as probably in all of your examples.

> Habe keine Angst, die Polizei ist ja bald `da`.
>   ('da' -> 'hier, bei uns')

"Da" can also be used to replace "dort", which refers to an explicit location. You can identify that meaning when information on that location is given in the sentence/context:

> Ich besuchte John im Spital. Mark war auch `da`.
>   ('da' -> 'im Spital')

Comment: With "there", I meant any possible location, so I'm not making a difference between things that are close to me or not. "Da" is indeed directly translated with "there" as it's explained in the second part. I improved that now.

Comment: Also note *Dasein=existence*.